# e.Graphics or Graphics.FromImage(New Bitmap(Width, Height))

Tags: performance, themes, controls, gdi+

So, I'm making a theme, should I use the PaintEventArgs' graphics or create a new one from the Width and Height? Which method is better and why?

Comment: There is no conceivable reason to not use the e.Graphics object you get from the Paint event.  Doing so only causes misery and it is never faster or "better".

Comment: Thanks for your response, no problem, beacause I only used e.Graphics.